# I am trying to search city in angular js but not working

Tags: html, angularjs

Here is plunker link for example please look and and tell me what is wrong? 
    [plunker link](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/w7GGclponWXluYB5?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview)

Comment: try to post some code for the same and simplify the question. Searching City is a use case which you want to acheive , but try to ask the logic instead and what all you have tried yet. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Plunkr is unclear of what you want to acheive

Comment: there is already list of cities. just I want to populate city when I enter text into textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is you have not loaded proper library (AngularJs, app.js) into your plunker which is mandatory and also it is not a proper html code to execute it from plunker, so I have created plunker for you with the proper code. Please find the code below,

Also your **$scope.Locations** is a string in your posted code but is should be an array type in order to do the loop by ng-repeat. I have corrected that too in the below controller code:

Please check this working [plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/mqW2122jbGj3KrSG).

**Controller:**

```
$scope.Locations = [
      {location:'pune'},
      {location:'Mumbai'}
  ];
```

**Template:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.6"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <label class="control-label"><b>City Name:</b></label>
    <input type="text" class="span3" id="LocCity" name="LocCity" ng-model="LocCity" ng-keyup="LocSearchCity(LocCity)" autocomplete="off" required />
      <ul class="list-group" ng-model="LocCityDropdown" ng-hide="LocCityDropdown">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="Location in Locations | filter: LocCity as LocSearchResult">
          <a href="#" ng-click="FillTextboxLocCity(Location)">
            {{Location.location}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p id="test"></p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great. If it helped you then feel free to mark it as green check and give a thumbs up if you really feel good.. Happy coding ;).